# euro sign in CSV file can not be displayed correctly in Mac Excel 2011

Tags: excel, scala, csv, playframework, export-to-csv

I want to generate the CSV file for download in scala with play framework. The downloaded CSV file looks fine on linux but it can't display euro sign correctly. Be more specific, the € can be correctly shown on linux and text edit on Mac. But it shows â‚¬ when opened by Excel Mac2011. I did some research and found it to be related to UTF encoding. However, even when I use utf-16 instead, it is still the same.

The following is my code snipet. Assuming that mydata:String is the content I need to write in CSV.

```
val content = mydata.getBytes("utf-16")
val inputstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content)
val fileContent: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.fromStream(inputstream)
val fileName = "attachment; filename=myCsvTest.csv"
Ok.chunked(fileContent).withHeaders(CONTENT_ENCODING -> "utf-16", CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/x-download" ,  CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> fileName)
```

}

Please give some advices. Thank you.

Comment: thanks, pnuts. I am wondering how to add BOM for utf-16 in scala.

Comment: finally, I found out that by using the "Cp1252" solves the problem.